# How to check which one is checked or not using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two radio button in my view..

something like this..

```
 <input type="radio" name="ObnCategory" id="Obncategory" checked="checked" />X</div><br />
  <div>
  <input type="radio" name="ObnCategory" id="Obnsubcategory" />Y</div><br />
```

I need to see which one is checked or not using jquery?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("input:radio:checked").val();
```

i.e.:

```
if ($("input:radio:checked").val() == "X") {

}
else if ($("input:radio:checked").val() == "Y") {

}
```

In your particular updated example try this:

```
$("input:radio:checked").next().text();
```

Comment: based on the OP's I think that can not be applied... :)

Answer (score 1):

why not add a `label`...

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="ObnCategory" id="Obncategory" checked="checked" />
    <label for="Obncategory">X</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="ObnCategory" id="Obnsubcategory" />
    <label for="Obnsubcategory">Y</label>
</div>
```

then

```
$(function(){
    $(':radio:checked').next('label').text() // would get the value
})
```

[play with the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/BZ3dU/)